# Search for String and get the next x characters

Tags: c#

So I have a very long string from an HTML page.

Example String:

NAME=test\nSERIAL=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx\nHWID=04017766253995646272764f55f8ef68be\nCOUNT=4\nCLASS=digital\nVERSION=25\nBRAND=testing\nEXPIRATION=\nSIGNATURE=GFMieP66BFZ2js+4KraGPoSK3GIFDVtf7+n8uizCiweNWOQ4b8NUc7jgRGP9+5N4oBxUoUe5jWfDL1qCnUFFtQ==\nSIGNATURE2=

I need to get the word SERIAL plus the next 69 characters from that string each time the word SERIAL appears. Then output to a textbox.

I can't find an example where a string is searched for a specific word, and return that word plus the next 69 characters.

EDIT:

string keys = richTextBox1.Text.ToString();
string[] splitkeys = keys.Substring(keys.IndexOf("SERIAL"), 76);

```
        foreach (string key in splitkeys)
        {
            //var split = keys.Substring(keys.IndexOf("SERIAL"), 76);

            richTextBox2.AppendText(key);
            richTextBox2.AppendText("\n\n");
        }
```

Comment: Either use `IndexOf` to determine the starting position, and then take a `Substring()` of the number of characters you want, or take a look at what determines this format, which would appear to be "Key=Value-pairs separated by `\n`". So you could split the string on `\n`, and look for the keys you're interested in (looks like "SERIAL", "HWID" and "COUNT"), and parse those, using a loop, a `StartsWith()` and `IndexOf()` or a `Split()` again. Because maybe not all serials or counts are the length you expect them to, so hardcoding that length may not be a good idea after all.

Comment: `input.Substring(input.IndexOf("SERIAL"),75)` (75 because `SERIAL` is 6 more characters)

Comment: @Jamiec yeah and now the next serial is 10 characters shorter or has a length attribute of 42.

Comment: @CodeCaster indeed, at that point OP needs to learn to write a better question.

Comment: My apologies for my poor question. I appreciate all the replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string NAME = "test\nSERIAL=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx\nHWID=04017766253995646272764f55f8ef68be\nCOUNT=4\nCLASS=digital\nVERSION=25\nBRAND=testing\nEXPIRATION=\nSIGNATURE=GFMieP66BFZ2js+4KraGPoSK3GIFDVtf7+n8uizCiweNWOQ4b8NUc7jgRGP9+5N4oBxUoUe5jWfDL1qCnUFFtQ==\nSIGNATURE2=";

NAME = NAME.Substring(NAME.IndexOf("SERIAL"), 69 + 6);
```

Comment: Yes this will work, how can I put this into a foreach loop?